# Finding the original location of a nested tag with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a set of tags that I'm trying to pull out of XML text and determine their location in the 'rendered' text.

For example:

XML:

```
<p>The risk of sexual transmission of HIV-1 correlates strongly with plasma HIV-1 level.
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="pone.0012598-Fideli1">[1]</xref>, 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="pone.0012598-Quinn1">[2]</xref>This association has motivated proposed interventions (such as use of antiretroviral therapy (ART),
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="pone.0012598-Cohen1">[3]</xref>, 
  <xref ref-type="bibr" rid="pone.0012598-Granich1">[4]</xref> therapeutic HIV-1 vaccines,<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="pone.0012598-Gurunathan1">[5]</xref> and treatment for co-infections<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="pone.0012598-Corey1">[6]</xref>–<xref ref-type="bibr" rid="pone.0012598-Walson1">[8]</xref> that reduce HIV-1 infectiousness by reducing levels of plasma HIV-1 RNA.
```

Rendered:

> The risk of sexual transmission of HIV-1 correlates strongly with plasma HIV-1 level.[1], [2] This association has motivated proposed interventions (such as use of antiretroviral therapy (ART),[3], [4] therapeutic HIV-1 vaccines,[5] and treatment for co-infections[6]–[8] that reduce HIV-1 infectiousness by reducing levels of plasma HIV-1 RNA.

In order to pull out the  tags and their locations in the rendered text. Currently I'm using `bs4` and something similar to this code (`sent_tokenize` is from the NLTK toolbox and creates a `list` of sentences from an input text):

```
for n, p in enumerate(article.find_all('p')):
    rawtext = str(p) #returns the XML version of the text
    readtext = p.text #returns the rendered version
    sents = sent_tokenize(readtext) #splits sentences

    for ref in p.find_all('xref'):
        startloc = rawtext.find(str(ref))
        prestart = max(0, startloc-20)
        for s in sents:
            if s.find(rawtext[prestart:startloc]) > -1:
                print s, ref
                break
```

This code fails to find the on the second xref because the text immediately before it is part of the previous xref tag.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a BeautifulSoup quiestion? BeautifulSoup uses `findAll` not `find_all`  this appears to be mixing BeautifulSoup (maybe), and text in an incompatable way.  `p.findAll('xref')` appears to work fine.

Comment: I'm using `bs4`, the new BeautifulSoup parser which uses `find_all` instead of `findAll`. Also, I have no problem extracting the tags, its finding their position in the rendered text that I'm having difficulty with.

Comment: Got it, i can't reproduce your error but my sent_tokenize could be returning different results (config stuff).  Also there is more than one `find` so it's hard to tell where your error is (rawtext.find or s.find)

Comment: It doesn't error-out but instead produces the incorrect results. The text ~20 characters upstream of the xref with the id: "pone.0012598-Quinn1" are not in the rendered text (because they are part of the preceding tag) so they won't be found using a text-search. So I was hoping there was a way to use BeautifulSoup to retrieve the position of the tag within the rendered text so I don't have to rely on a text-search.

Comment: BeautifulSoup rocks but I'm not aware of it doing this.  I'll watch this thread hoping to learn if it does.  I do know that it could be done in [Genshi][http://genshi.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/filters.html#transformer] as a Genshi stream carries the position info with each SAX like event for debug purposes.  You could count the len of text events to know the position in "rendered" text.  Not what you asked for but that's a tool that would get the job done.

Comment: @PhilCooper, that's pretty much what I had to go with. I just counted the nested string-lengths and then used `bisect` to determine which sentence it came from.

Answer (score 1):

Well, nobody responded so I had to improvise. This is my current method:

```
lens = [len(tag.string) for tag in p.contents]
clens = [sum(lens[:ind]) for ind in xrange(1,len(lens))]
locs = [spot for tag, spot in zip(p.contents, clens) if isinstance(tag, Tag) and tag.name == 'xref']
```

The basic idea is the use the `string` method which returns the rendered text. I use that to determine lengths of each child of the paragraph. Then I use those lengths to determine the position of the tags that I'm looking for.

Hope that helps someone else!

-Will